# How do I distinguish London time from UTC stored in DatTimeOffset?

Tags: .net, datetime, utc, datetimeoffset

I use the `DateTimeOffset` type to store date and time. In some cases this type contains local time and offset from UTC, in other cases - UTC time.

In the past I was using `DateTime.Kind` to distinguish these cases. However there is no `Kind` property exists in `DateTimeOffset` type.

How do I distinguish if this is a London time with a zero offset stored in `DateTimeOffset` or this is a UTC time?

Comment: In general, you can't.  Even with `DateTime`, `.Kind` is not usually retained when the `DateTime` is persisted.  Even then, you only have `Utc`, `Local` or `Unspecified`.  Unless you already know your local zone is London, you can't tell.  The `Unspecified` kind could just as easily be UTC, London, Iceland, West Africa, or many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeOffset only stores UTC offset data, not timezone data which also includes DST properties. So if you want to store "what time zone this DateTimeOffset object belongs to" kind of data, you'll want to use System.TimeZoneInfo.

My suggestion is to create a class (something like "DateTimeOffsetWithTimeZone" that has two members, a DateTimeOffset and a TimeZoneInfo. When setting an instance of this for London time, you could assign to the TimeZoneInfo member the following:

```
myInstance.TZInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
```

Comment: [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) has a `ZonedDateTime` type for this exact purpose.